# Optimization of CPU pipelining and cache access

Tags: c++, caching, cpu, hpc, cpu-cache

I am trying to build intuition about how to write efficient code that minimizes CPI (cycles per instruction) and minimizes cache misses and back-end bound performance. I want to understand how data locality and pipelining interact.

I understand that a lot of these things depend on specific hardware, and it is impossible to answer with certainty. Still, I am hoping some reasonable guidance on what would 'probably' happen on a 'typical' desktop computer, using a program compiled with a common compiler like gcc or icpc and -O2.

Consider the following (contrived) code. The purpose of this code is to set up different scenarios to illustrate the question. Let's assume a cache line is 64 bytes. (edit) - To clarify, let's assume that none of these variables are in any level of cache at the time that calc is executed. A response correctly pointed out that if any are already cached, this would impact the result.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {};
    inline void calc(const double in);
private:
    double x,y[10],z[32],a,b;
};

inline void MyClass:calc(const double in) 
{
    x = 5 + in;
    y[0] = 10 + in;
    z[0] = 25 + in;
    a = 50 + in;
    q = 100 + in;//q is a variable from global scope that is not already in the cache
    *pq = 200 + in;//*pq is a pointer from global scope that is not already in the cache
    q2 = 300 + in;//q2 is a variable from global scope that is not already in the cache
    b = 400 + in;
    cout << x << ", " << y[0] << ", " << z[0] << ", " << a << ", " << q << ", " << *pq << ", " << q2 << "," << b;
}
```

When calc is run, x and y[0] are probably on the same cache line, so y[0] will be accessed with a cache hit? z[0] is on the next cache line. However, it might benefit from a 'next cache line' prefetch and also be a cache hit? a is several cache lines away, and then q is a variable from the global scope that is located in some remote location in memory. Even though a is several cache lines from z[0], should we expect it to be loaded into the processor faster than q? Would there perhaps be some kind of prefetch at a higher level of cache that would possibly prevent a from being a total cache miss? q will surely require a pull from main memory, since it is from a remote location in memory. *pq and q will also require their own pull from main memory.

So my expectation is that something like this happens: y[0] would load with an L1 cache hit, z[0] might load with an L1 or L2 cache hit, a may or may not be an L2 cache hit, and q would definitely be a cache miss. What if q is so far away that it also causes a TLB cache miss? Then it would be even slower? Is my understanding of all this correct?

How does pipelining affect this? The processor could pipeline the series of memory loads, bringing q in from main memory to the cache prior to the completion of the previous line of code. Thus, in practice, would we observe slowdown from the use of variable q, which is in a remote location in memory?

Note that calc is inlined, so its instructions might form part of a larger chain of operations in the function that calls it, which I assume would help with pipelining.

How does the variable *pq affect pipelining? The compiler doesn't know whether *pq is a pointer that points to q2 or to b. Would this affect the efficacy of pipelining?

Finally, we arrive at b. It is on the same cache line as a. We've had to do several things since we last used a, but hopefully it's still in the L1 cache and a hit? Again, could the use of the pointer *pq (which might point to b) impact optimizations here?

Comment: _`x` and `y[0]` are on the same cache line_. There is no such guarantee. Objects of `MyClass` are generally not aligned to cache boundaries (extended alignment requirements may force this). Anyway, I recommend to read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf).

Comment: Fair point on x and y[0]. I should have said that they will 'probably' be on the same cache line. Also, thank you for the recommendation on the reading. In fact, I read that article yesterday. This question is motivated by my attempt to synthesize what I read, confirm that my understanding is correct, and clear up lingering questions.

Comment: Fair enough :). The problem is that you ask a "million" questions at once, and IMO many of them cannot be simply answered (or, you could write long research article about these topics). For instance, you cannot make any assumptions about how hardware prefetching will be applied. It does not only depend on architecture, but it can substantially differ beween executions of the same machine code. The only think you can do is to profile your program, for example with hardware counters.

Comment: "CPI (cycles per instruction)" - I think you got that backwards. One usually want to maximize IPC (Instructions Per Clock) ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Thanks for pointing out the typo. I am changing it to say 'minimize' CPI.

Comment: @DanielLangr - I am currently profiling a large code base with VTune. It is very helpful. However, a purely empirical approach does not help design solutions to problems, and ideally, you'd like to have good intuition so that you write code that is well-written the first time around, without having to go back profile and revise everything. I know these are complex questions and generalizations are impossible. I am looking for general, practical responses, not a precise, certain answer. And yes, it's a lot of questions, but they are closely interrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions.

The compiler may align MyClass objects by more than 8, especially if they are in static memory, so x and y[0] are likely to be in the same cache line. Most compilers will align big objects more than small objects.

If the MyClass object is declared locally, it will be stored on the stack. In this case it is likely that the entire object is in the L1 cache.

z[0] may be prefetched by the hardware, but perhaps not early enough.

The first five lines may be executed out of order because they are independent. This means that any cache miss on one line will not slow down the next lines.

You are right that *pq = something prevents out-of-order execution because (in the general case) the compiler does not know if *pq is an alias of some of the other variables.

'a' is not necessarily loaded faster than 'q'. For example, if they are both in the level-2 cache they would load equally fast. It does not depend on the distance but on the time since they were last touched. A TLB miss or page boundary may of course affect the fetch time if both are in main RAM and q is far away.

b will stay cached if it is in the same cache line as a, but you cannot access b until the address of *pq has been resolved and found not to alias on b.

Inlining the calc function makes no difference here if we assume that data caching is a bottleneck, while code caching is not.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. I especially like your point about out of order execution. I'd like to ask for a bit of clarification. My intent was that none of these variables were in any level of cache prior to the execution of calc. So under those conditions, the question is asking: (1) does a potentially load faster because of its (moderate) proximity to z? (2) does q potentially load very slow if the overall program is using a ton of memory and q leads to a TLB miss?, and  (3) is the compiler able to partly or entirely mitigate these delays by prefetching into the pipeline?

Comment: @pah52. (1) no 'a' does not load faster because of proximity.
(2) yes, a TLB miss could make q load slower. (3) No, the compiler does not normally insert prefetch instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I guess 'a' could load faster than q if there was a TLB miss, but interesting that it doesn't matter otherwise.